# Should I set the Firebase dabase to offline when my Node.js app is offline?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm developing a desktop app based on `Node.js (Electron)` which collects data from user's computer and sends it to `Firebase Realtime database` via `Firebase Node.js` module.

When user is offline I'd like to still collect the data and send it to `Firebase` once there is a connection, but I'm a bit confused how it's done. Apparently based on the documentations Firebase does this (performing the `put` and `set` locally and sending data once online) automatically as long as the session is alive (which means my app is still running and not closed), is this correct?

In the documentations there are 2 methods `firebase.database().goOffline();` and `firebase.database().goOnline();`, should I constantly watch the internet connection and set Firabse to offline and online in my code? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to call the `goOffline()`/`goOnline()` methods, unless you explicitly want to control whether the Firebase client connects/tries to connect to its server.

With the default behavior: once the network connection is restored, the Firebase client will automatically reconnect and send any pending updates.

Comment: Hi Frank, a previous post of yours said that the NodeJS client doesn't support offline mode.  Has this changed?  Thanks!

Comment: @Frank it doesn't work we tried with a NodeJS Application and it doesn't sync a data when an app comes online. Also, if the internet goes off and on then after none of the data sync with firebase server. Is there any specific code for the same or reference?